# How to connect oracle from shell

Tags: oracle, shell

My Oracle username is `system` password is `oracle10g` and I have to connect using `sysdba` mode from `TOAD`. Now I have to connect from shell to call a stored procedure in Oracle.

Comment: Please provide us the connection string as well.

Comment: what do you mean by connection string

Comment: The IP address, domain, port number, SID and service name of your Oracle server and its process. :P

Comment: IP:192.168.1.2 port:1521 sid:orcl service:orcl

Comment: Don't exhaust his faith in human being, I guess we all know it was fake passwords :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but this might help:

When I connect from a command prompt/shell I use the following syntax:

```
sqlplus schema_name/password@database_alias
```

Of course you should have sqlplus installed(which probably you definitely have)
database_alias is the database name you provide when you log in via toad(database name as mentioned in the tnsnames.ora) file